# AWS Deployment of Next.js 13 App directory + Express.js API + RDS database

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, next.js, deployment

I have an existing Express.js API that I want to call from my Next.js frontend. My Next.js app is using its own API route for NextAuth.

I have a postgres database already deployed on RDS.

Can I deploy both the Next app and the Express API on beanstalk at once? If that is possible, how would I do that since I would need to upload my files and I currently have separate folders for my Express app and my Next app, each of them with its own package.json

I have seen people suggest using Amplify for Next and Beanstalk for the API but it seems to cause problems because Amplify uses HTTPS and Beanstalk would require an SSL certificate to get it working.

Other people suggested using S3/Cloudfront when deploying MERN apps but the problem is that my Next app is using API routes for NextAuth.

Finally I thought about using docker and deploying it using Beanstalk or ECS but I am not sure if I would face complications connecting my existing RDS instance to it.

Keep in mind I am a beginner to all of this especially AWS and app deployment. If I got something wrong please let me know.

P.S. I am required to deploy to AWS or else I would have looked into Vercel for my Next app.